# Why is this comparison only works for integer type id?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am wondering does the statement `[@id=current()/@id]` can only work if the id is integer for example:

```
<elem id="1">
<elem id="1">
```

But if I have:

```
<elem id="AAA">
<elem id="AAA">
```

It does not work.

My XSL where it fails:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:tn="http://"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn tn">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="genre/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

            <xsl:apply-templates select="
     book[@id=current()/@id][@action='extend']                             
         [not( preceding-sibling::book[@id=current()/@id][@action='borrow'])]" />

            <xsl:for-each-group
                select="book[@id=current()/@id][@action='borrow'] 
             |   
            book[@id=current()/@id][@action='extend']
                [preceding-sibling::book[@id=current()/@id][@action='borrow']]"
                group-starting-with="book[@action='borrow']">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[1]">
                    <xsl:copy>   
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                        <xsl:call-template name="merge-books-deeply">    
                            <xsl:with-param name="books" select="current-group()" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="name-path" select="()" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>     
            </xsl:for-each-group>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="                             
     node()[ not( self::book[@id=current()/@id][@action=('borrow','extend')])]" />

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="tn:children-on-path" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="base" as="element()*" />   
        <xsl:param name="path" as="xs:string*" />    
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="fn:empty($base)">
                <xsl:sequence select="()" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="fn:empty($path)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$base/*" />     
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="tn:children-on-path(
     $base/*[name()=$path[1]],         
     $path[position() ne 1])" /> 
            </xsl:otherwise>  
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template name="merge-books-deeply">
        <xsl:param name="books" as="element()*" />
        <xsl:param name="name-path" as="xs:string*" />
        <xsl:for-each-group
            select="tn:children-on-path($books,$name-path)"
            group-by="name()">                                             
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[last()]" >  
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                    <xsl:call-template name="merge-books-deeply"> 
                        <xsl:with-param name="books" select="$books" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="name-path" select="$name-path,name()" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />        
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

input sample where it works:

```
<root> 
    <library id="L1">
        <genre id="a">
            <shelf1 id="1">                
                <book id="1" action="borrow">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>John</user>                    
                    </attributes>
                    <other1>y</other1>
                </book>  
                <book id="1" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>Woo</user>           
                        <length>3</length>
                    </attributes>
                    <other2>y</other2>
                </book>  
                <book id="1" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <length>2</length>
                        <condition>ok</condition>
                    </attributes>
                    <other3>y</other3>
                </book>
                <book id="2" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <length>99</length>
                        <condition>not-ok</condition>
                    </attributes>
                    <other>y</other>
                </book>
            </shelf1>
            <shelf1 id="b">...
            </shelf1>

        </genre>
        <genre id="b">...
        </genre>
    </library>
</root>
```

If I change the id of the book to `1a`:

```
<root> 
    <library id="L1">
        <genre id="a">
            <shelf1 id="1">                
                <book id="1a" action="borrow">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>John</user>                    
                    </attributes>
                    <other1>y</other1>
                </book>  
                <book id="1a" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>Woo</user>           
                        <length>3</length>
                    </attributes>
                    <other2>y</other2>
                </book>  
                <book id="1a" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <length>2</length>
                        <condition>ok</condition>
                    </attributes>
                    <other3>y</other3>
                </book>
                <book id="2" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <length>99</length>
                        <condition>not-ok</condition>
                    </attributes>
                    <other>y</other>
                </book>
            </shelf1>
            <shelf1 id="b">...
            </shelf1>

        </genre>
        <genre id="b">...
        </genre>
    </library>
</root>
```

My Error Output: (it doesn't merge at all)

```
<root> 
    <library id="L1">
        <genre id="a">
            <shelf1 id="1">                
                <book id="a1" action="borrow">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>John</user>                    
                    </attributes>
                    <other1>y</other1>
                </book>  
                <book id="a1" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>Woo</user>           
                        <length>3</length>
                    </attributes>
                    <other2>y</other2>
                </book>  
                <book id="a1" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <length>2</length>
                        <condition>ok</condition>
                    </attributes>
                    <other3>y</other3>
                </book>
                <book id="2" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <length>99</length>
                        <condition>not-ok</condition>
                    </attributes>
                    <other>y</other>
                </book>
            </shelf1>
            <shelf1 id="b">...
            </shelf1>

        </genre>
        <genre id="b">...
        </genre>
    </library>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root> 
    <library id="L1">
        <genre id="a">
            <shelf1 id="1">                
                <book id="1a" action="borrow">
                    <attributes>
                        <user>Woo</user>           
                        <length>2</length>
                        <condition>ok</condition>                  
                    </attributes>
                    <other1>y</other1>
                </book>  
                <book id="2" action="extend">
                    <attributes>
                        <length>99</length>
                        <condition>not-ok</condition>
                    </attributes>
                    <other>y</other>
                </book>
            </shelf1>
            <shelf1 id="b">...
            </shelf1>

        </genre>
        <genre id="b">...
        </genre>
    </library>
</root>
```

For every node with action=borrow followed by one or more node with action=extend

- Merge it together to the node with action=borrow.
- Merge the attributes children together such that it will have all the unique attributes from the siblings with the latest value.
- leave other children unchanged

THe merging only happen with node that has the same id.

Thanks.
Regards,
John

Comment: It should work. What is your evidence that it doesn't?

Comment: @MichaelKay please have a look at the added example, am I missing something there ? Thanks very much

Comment: @John, what's missing is (a) the description of what the result was, and (b) the description of what you expected the result to be. "Does not work" is just too vague. (Also, it would help if your example data was usable; as it is, it's not a well-formed XML document.)

Comment: @John: Please, provide a small, but *complete* example. People are guessing -- *again* !

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Please see my added complete example. Thank you.

Comment: @John: It still isn't complete -- the XSLT code is missing. With the current question, no one can repro the problem, because the XSLT code is missing. Also for the "bad case" you provide the expected output, but you don't provide the actual output and how/where it differs from the expected output. Please, edit and provide the missing information.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Added the XSLT code, Please let me know in which part I made the mistake. Thanks very much.

Comment: @John: I was asking for a *small* example -- not for 84 lines of complicated XSLT 2.0 code. Your biggest problem is that you have accumulated such voluminous code -- probably not fully understanding what it does. Don't expect people to look enthusiastically into such code -- most would rather rewrite it from scratch (because this is easier to do than to find one of possibly many mistakes in someone elses code). The best recommendation I have is to get a good book on XSLT and XPath and to read it and understand it well. Never write such long code. Learn from small examples and write short code.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are having a context issue instead. The comparisons should work. Here's an example...

**XML Input**

```
<tests>
    <test>
        <elem id="1"/>
        <elem id="1"/>
    </test>
    <test>
        <elem id="AAA"/>
        <elem id="AAA"/>
    </test>
    <test>
        <elem id="BBB"/>
        <elem id="CCC"/>
    </test>
    <test>
        <elem id="2"/>
        <elem id="3"/>
    </test>
</tests>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="elem[1]">
        <xsl:text>Comparing id </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',@id,'&quot;&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;',
            boolean(following-sibling::*[@id=current()/@id]),
            '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Comparing id "1"
    true
Comparing id "AAA"
    true
Comparing id "BBB"
    false
Comparing id "2"
    false
```

---

**Edit**

After looking at your updated examples it definitely looks like a context issue. Take a look at the start of the template:

```
<xsl:template match="genre/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

            <xsl:apply-templates select="
     book[@id=current()/@id][@action='extend']                             
         [not( preceding-sibling::book[@id=current()/@id][@action='borrow'])]" />
```

Notice that the match is `genre/*`; that's the current context. With your input that's going to be `shelf1`. Then the select of the second `xsl:apply-templates` starts with `book[@id=current()/@id]`. To me this looks like it is selecting `book` if it has an `id` attribute that equals the `id` attribute of `shelf1`. To test this you could also change the `id` of `shelf1` to `1a` and it would probably work. (That's the reason the first example works; the `id` of `shelf1` and `book` match.

I can't test this theory right now, but I think that is the reason it appears that the comparison isn't working. (It is working, you're just not comparing what you think you're comparing.)

Comment: Please have a look at the added example, am I missing something there? What does it mean by context issue? Thanks very much.

Comment: @John - Like Dimitre said in a comment, please add a complete example. This includes an XML example that reproduces the issue when your example XSLT is applied.

Comment: Please see my added example, and advise me where I miss. Thanks very much

Comment: You are correct!! it does work, means that shelf1 id is being compared with book id. But if I remove the `[@id=current()/@id]` in the second xsl:apply-templates, it still doesn't work. Any suggestion to fix it so that it only compares the book id only ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison does not require explicit string conversion. In other words, it should work as you've written it. Here's an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="elem">
    <xsl:if test="count(../elem[@id=current()/@id]) &gt; 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>: has dup
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input:

```
<r>
    <elem id="AAA">one</elem>
    <elem id="AAA">two</elem>
    <elem id="ZZZ">three</elem>
</r>
```

The following output is produced:

```
AAA: has dup
AAA: has dup
```

From [the XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans):

> Otherwise, if at least one object to be compared is a number, then
>   each object to be compared is converted to a number as if by applying
>   the number function. Otherwise, both objects to be compared are
>   converted to strings as if by applying the string function.